Laravel 10.48.22 update function not updating data on database

I just learn to create rest api using laravel
I have table user, user model and auth controller
The register and login api running well
When I want to update user data (ex: name), the response return success but the data in database not change / updating

Here's my code
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        // Check if the authenticated user is allowed to update this user
        if (Auth::user()->role !== 'admin' && Auth::id() !== $user->id) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthorized'], 403);
        }

        // Validate the request data
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'sometimes|required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'sometimes|required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,' . $user->id,
            'password' => 'sometimes|required|string|min:8|confirmed',
            'role' => 'sometimes|required|string|in:user,admin',
            'image' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            'address' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'latitude' => 'nullable|numeric|between:-90,90',
            'longitude' => 'nullable|numeric|between:-180,180',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        // Update user fields
        if ($request->has('name')) {
            $user->name = $request->input('name');
        }

        if ($request->has('email')) {
            $user->email = $request->input('email');
        }

        if ($request->has('password')) {
            $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        }

        if ($request->has('role')) {
            $user->role = $request->input('role');
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $imagePath = $request->file('image')->store('images', 'public');
            $user->image = $imagePath;
        }

        if ($request->has('address')) {
            $user->address = $request->input('address');
        }

        // Handle location data
        if ($request->filled('latitude') && $request->filled('longitude')) {
            $longitude = $request->input('longitude');
            $latitude = $request->input('latitude');
            $user->location = new Point($longitude, $latitude);
        }

        // Save updated user data
        $user->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'User updated successfully',
            'user' => $user,
        ], 200);
    }

I expect the data in database updating when success update through api

You've dumped a lot of code here. Any chance you can remove parts of the code but still get the same issue? i.e. is validation necessary here? are we assuming valid input? Are all the controller functions relevant?


I solve it using method POST in postman instead of PUT
When I see the route:list it's show that the method is PUT for update function.
I don't know why PUT in laravel using POST with suffix ?_method=PUT


Is this meant to be a solution? Some explanation of what it's meant to be would help

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
